# Dividing the density scale in to more ranges of map in R

Tags: r, ggmap

Hi I'm very new to R language. 
I was trying to plot the density of three crimes in a map.

```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(ggmap)
  library(dplyr)

  map <- read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
  map<-get_map(location = 'san fransisco', zoom=14, maptype = "watercolor",source='osm',color='color')

  lims <- coord_map(xlim=c(-122.47, -122.37), ylim=c(37.70, 37.81))


  mapdata <-
    train %>%
    filter(Category %in% c("LARCENY/THEFT", "ASSAULT", "DRUG/NARCOTIC"))

  contours <- stat_density2d(
    aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = ..level.., alpha=0.3),
    size = 0.8, data = mapdata, n=1000,
    geom = "polygon")

  ggmap(map, extent='device') + lims + contours +
    scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0.4,0.8), guide='none') +
    scale_fill_gradient('Violent\nCrime\nDensity') +
    facet_wrap(~Category) +
    ggtitle('Violent Crime in San Francisco')
```

The scale of this has divided only in to 3 sections. If I need to divide it into more sections how it is possible to be done instead of R to decide it. And how it is possible to change the color of the scale. ex: highest density for a darker color and lower density to light color. Are there any explanatory tutorials to refer.

[image]

Comment: The scale you are plotting on the colors is continuous. If you find any grouping it indicates this reflects the information in your data. By adjusting breaks in `scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: Oh gawd, what a mess of a comment. This was written around 5 o'clock in the morning. What I meant was if there are any patterns in the result, it's probably the result of the way your values are distributed. To control where to switch colors, try using `scale_fill_manual`.